Per the Rambam, Is There a Thematic Nexus Between the Final Paragraph of Shema and the First Two?
The Rambam (Laws of Shema 1:2) articulates the three paragraphs of Shema and their proper order:


וּמַה הוּא קוֹרֵא, שְׁלֹשָׁה פָּרָשִׁיּוֹת. אֵלּוּ הֵן (דברים ו ד) ״שְׁמַע״ (דברים יא יג) ״וְהָיָה אִם שָׁמֹעַ״ (במדבר טו לז) ״וַיֹּאמֶר״. וּמַקְדִּימִין לִקְרוֹת פָּרָשַׁת שְׁמַע מִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ יִחוּד הַשֵּׁם וְאַהֲבָתוֹ וְתַלְמוּדוֹ שֶׁהוּא הָעִקָּר הַגָּדוֹל שֶׁהַכּל תָּלוּי בּוֹ. וְאַחֲרֶיהָ וְהָיָה אִם שָׁמֹעַ שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ צִוּוּי עַל (זְכִירַת) שְׁאָר כָּל הַמִּצְוֹת. וְאַחַר כָּךְ פָּרָשַׁת (במדבר טו לח) ״צִיצִית״ שֶׁגַּם הִיא יֵשׁ בָּהּ צִוּוּי זְכִירַת כָּל הַמִּצְוֹת:

And what is it that one recites? These three sections:
"Hear O Israel..." (Deuteronomy 6:4-9),
"And if you will listen..." (Deuteronomy 11:13-21),and
"And God said..." (Numbers 15:37-41).
We begin with the section of "Hear O Israel" since it contains [the concept of] the unity of God, [the commandment of] loving Him and the study of Torah, it being a fundamental principle upon which everything is based.
After it, [we read] "And if you will listen...," since it contains the imperative to fulfill the rest of the commandments, and finally the portion of tzitzit, since it also contains the imperative of remembering all the commandments.

He further states (1:3) that the final paragraph is also read at night along with the first two:
.
אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין מִצְוַת צִיצִית נוֹהֶגֶת בַּלַּיְלָה קוֹרְאִין אוֹתָהּ בַּלַּיְלָה מִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ זִכְרוֹן יְצִיאַת מִצְרַיִם וּמִצְוָה לְהַזְכִּיר יְצִיאַת מִצְרַיִם בַּיּוֹם וּבַלַּיְלָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים טז ג) ״לְמַעַן תִּזְכֹּר אֶת יוֹם צֵאתְךָ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם כּל יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ״. וּקְרִיאַת שָׁלֹשׁ פָּרָשִׁיּוֹת אֵלּוּ עַל סֵדֶר זֶה הִיא הַנִּקְרֵאת קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע:

The commandment of tzitzit is not obligatory at night. Nevertheless, we recite [the section describing] it at night because it contains mention of the exodus from Egypt.
We are commanded to mention the exodus both during the day and at night as [Deuteronomy 16:3] states: "In order that you shall remember the day of your leaving the land of Egypt all the days of your life."
Reading these three sections in this order constitutes the recitation of the Shema.

The Kesef Mishna (1:2) asks a powerful question:

. וא"ת למה לי טעם שיש בה צווי זכירת המצות תיפוק ליה משום שיש בה זכירת יציאת מצרים ומצוה להזכיר יציאת מצרים ביום ובלילה י"ל שאילו לא היינו קורין אותה אלא מטעם יציאת מצרים לא היינו מצרפים אותה עם שמע והיה אם שמוע שאינה מענינם אבל לפי שיש בה ציווי זכירת כל המצות נצטרפה עם פרשיות אלו וכיון שנצטרפה להם בקריאת היום אע"פ שמצות ציצית אינה נוהגת אלא ביום לא ראו חכמים לחלק בין יום ולילה:
Why do I need the reason (for the third paragraph being part of Shema) of it contains the imperative of remembering the other mitzvot? Just say that (the reason it is part of Shema) is because it contains a mention of the exodus from Egypt and there is a command to remember/mention the exodus day and night! One can answer as such – if the only reason that we read (the final paragraph) is due to the exodus, we would not have made it (the final paragraph) part of Shema because it is off topic. But because that paragraph does contain the imperative of remembering the other mitzvot (which is conceptually related to the first two paragraphs) it is joined to these paragraphs (the first two) ….

The Mirkevet Hamishna (M”H) responds to the K”M’s thought by quoting the end of the first chapter of B’rachot :


Brachot 13b: פָּרָשַׁת צִיצִית מִפְּנֵי מָה קְבָעוּהָ?


Why was the portion of ritual fringes established as part of the recitation of Shema when its content is unrelated to that of the preceding portions?
אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוּדָה בַּר חֲבִיבָא, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ חֲמִשָּׁה דְּבָרִים: מִצְוַת צִיצִית, יְצִיאַת מִצְרַיִם, עוֹל מִצְוֹת, וְדַעַת מִינִים, הִרְהוּר עֲבֵירָה, וְהִרְהוּר עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה.
Rabbi Yehuda bar Ḥaviva said: The portion of ritual fringes was added because it includes five elements including the primary reason for its inclusion, the exodus from Egypt (Melo HaRo’im): The mitzva of ritual fringes, mention of the exodus from Egypt, the acceptance of the yoke of mitzvot, admonition against the opinions of the heretics, admonition against thoughts of the transgressions of licentiousness, and admonition against thoughts of idolatry.

The M"H after the quoting the above gemarra states that ‘behold, this is explicitly the reason of our teacher of blessed memory, unlike what he (K”M) wrote that if the only reason that we read the final paragraph is due to the exodus, we would not have made it the final paragraph of Shema because it is off topic …”
Question – what is the meaning (after quoting the Talmud about five reasons) of ‘behold … this is the reason of our teacher”? Does M"H mean that the Rambam must recognize that there are really five reasons to explain why the final paragraph is part of Shema, and since several of these themes have no relationship to Shema it must also be true that the Rambam must acknowledge that the one reason that he chose to focus upon (Ol Mitzvot - reason three) must also have nothing thematically to do with Shema?
M"H underscores his point and states that this all disproves the K”M’s assertion that if we only had the theme of the exodus in the final paragraph we would not read it together with Shema. His proof is that Tzitzit, FE, is brought by the Talmud   as one reason for adding the third paragraph to Shema. Now tzizit qua a single Mitzva of the Torah (not qua its capacity to evoke a remembrance of all mitzvot) has little per se to do with Shema – thus M"H concludes one does NOT need a thematic connection between the final paragraph and the others.
The elephant in the room - The Rambam certainly goes out of his way to choose one reason only as to why we added the final paragraph and clearly makes the point that there is a thematic connection between all three paragraphs! This is truly what prompted the K"M to run with the point that there must be a thematic connection.
The real question here is what does the Rambam do with the Gemara?
